# Ask user to enable Call Blocking and Identification in Phone Settings

Tags: ios, callkit

I have implemented `CallKit` and `CallDirectoryExtension` in my app. Is there a way to ask the user in-app to enable this setting? Similar to how permissions for Contacts, Microphone, Camera are requested?

If not, what's the best way to navigate the user to this settings screen?

```
Settings -> Phone -> Call Blocking and Identification
```

[image: Call Blocking & Identification in Phone Settings]

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a Tech Support request with Apple and they said there is currently no way to do this.  FYI The current iOS production release at this time is: 10.0.2